# How to combine two columns from a database with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, ms-access

```
 // Appetizers Filter
        var Appetizers =
           from a in this.restaurantMenuDataSet.Menu
           where a.Category == "Appetizer"
           select a;
        foreach (var a in Appetizers) AppCombo.Items.Add(a.ItemName);
```

So with this I get appetizers from an access database, but I also want to display its `price` along side it in ComboList. So basically I want the list to show "Nachos $5.95"

Database:

[image]

ComboList:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`String.Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format) to combine `ItemName` and `Price` in order to display in combobox:

```
foreach (var a in Appetizers)
{
    var displayName = String.Format("{0} {1}", a.ItemName,a.Price);
    AppCombo.Items.Add(displayName);
}
```